# Proving from De Morgan's laws

Tags: boolean-algebra, boolean-ring

I was proving:

$J.K'.L+J.K.L'+JKL=J.(L+K)$

I have done the following:

From LHS:
$J.K'.L+J.K.L'+JKL$

$=J.(K'.L+K.L'+K.L)$

$=J.(K'.L+K.(L'+L))$

Since $L'+L=1:$

$=J.(K'L+K)$
[' is complement]

Now I'm unable to get the expression towards $X=J.(L+K)$

Could you please suggest me how I can prove this problem?

Comment: What are K.L, K', KL, and K+L?

Answer (score 2):

Nice progress. We will prove the identity
$$A+B=A+A'B$$
for general variables $A,B$. You can use a truth table to see that this is indeed true, but we will prove it algebraicly.

Start with
$$A+B$$
Since $A+A'=1$, this is equivalent to
$$=1(A+B)$$
$$=(A+A')(A+B)$$
Expanding, yields
$$=A+AB+AA'+A'B$$
$$=A(1+B)+1+A'B$$
$$=A+A'B$$

Hence, we have
$$J(K'L+K)=J(L+K)$$

Answer (score 1):

Distribution says: $P+QR=(P+Q)(P+R)$

So:

$K'L+K = (K'+K)(L+K) = 1(L+K)= L+K$